# Convert time in 43811.23287 (excel time) format human readable datetime with mins and secs removed

Tags: excel, excel-formula

1st I like to know what does this 43811.1234 time format is call?

2nd, I have a column full of datetime in the above format. How can I divide the time to give me the datetime with mins and secs removed?

Example 12/12/2019 09:06 becomes 12/12/2019 09:00?

8 Jan 2020: Thanks to Scott, I managed to find more information on excel time format. Here's a link for future readers. https://www.myonlinetraininghub.com/excel-date-and-time
https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2017/04/12/add-subtract-time-excel-over-24-hours/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Date time in Excel is stored as a Double.  The integer is the number of days since 1/1/1900 and the decimal is the part of one day.  so 12:00:00 is `.5`.  One mearly needs to format the number as a date/time to show the correct string.

To get the hour we can use MROUND to round to the nearest hour:

```
=MROUND(43811.1234,TIME(1,0,0))
```

Or if we want to remove the minutes and seconds(round down)

```
=INT(43811.1234*24)/24
```

[image]

Comment: Nice answer. `=MROUND(43811.1234,"01:00")` would work too =).

Comment: Thanks. I personally dislike the string conversion route.  Just personal preference and habit.

Comment: The MROUND answer doesn't seem to give the desired result, as the result in the example in  the question is rounded down.

Comment: @STHOH the example is rounded. `9:06` would round to `9:00`  And as to what the OP meant by `datetime in 1st hour` is anyone's guess.  so I gave both.  And who knows who will land here in the future and what they desire.

Comment: @JvdV BTW, it could also be `=MROUND(43811.1234,1/24)`

Comment: Hi All, I meant to round down actually. couldn't think of the term then. Just corrected my original question. INT method seems to work fine. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

With formula you could do something like the following:

Assuming you have the date value in cell A2:

=INT(A2)+TIME(HOUR(A2),0, 0)

Returns 12-12-19 02:00:00

Format it accordingly to the desired time format.

Answer (score 0):

In `A1` enter : `43811.1234`

In `A2` enter : `12/12/2019  9:06`

Then, select `A1:A2` >> `Custom Cell Format`, in the window box enter : `d/mm/yyyy hh\:\0\0` (or `mm/d/yyyy hh\:\0\0` in meet with your country date setting)

`A1`, will change to : `12/12/2019 02:00`

`A2`, will change to : `12/12/2019 09:00`

Edit :

If you wanted to actual remove the minutes

In `B1` enter formula and copied down :

```
=0+TEXT(A1,"d/mm/yyyy hh\:\0\0")
```

then >> Custom Cell Format, in the window box enter: `d/mm/yyyy hh:mm`

B1, return : `12/12/2019 02:00`

B2, return : `12/12/2019 09:00`

Comment: One note, to this method,  it does not actually change the value, but changes how the value is seen.  If doing any lookups or other references to the data it will look at the actual value and not formatted value.

Comment: Hi, Scott is right. I actually need the column for group by later so I need to remove the mins and secs. But thanks for the alternative.

Comment: @Scott Craner, I re-read the OP's post. you are right, I edit the post as per the OP required. Thanks